# What is the proper meaning of this sentence? Please explain this briefly

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence, sentence-meaning, cinema

In a Batman(2022) movie, in public memorial for mayor,there is a announcement that

> "As a reminder, the family asked that those wishing to honor the
> mayor's memory... consider a donation to the cause most dear to his
> heart... the Gotham Renewal Fund.."

But I don't get the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: Meaning is difficult to explain without a clue of what the issue is. What part of the sentence is causing difficulty? For instance, in approaching this sentence, is there a particular phrase you don't understand? Do you want to read it a specific way but find something in the sentence contradicting that reading?

Comment: Welcome. There are many phrases in this sentence; right now this question is too broad to answer. To get a meaningful answer, please use the "edit" button to explain more about the part that confuses you. Is there a particular word or phrase that you're unfamiliar with? Please also show that you've looked up any uncertain words in a dictionary, what you found, and what questions remain.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to take out some of the extraneous phrases:

> <s>As a reminder,</s> the family asked that those [people] <s>wishing to honor the mayor's memory...</s> consider a donation <s>to the cause most dear to his heart... the Gotham Renewal Fund.</s>

At a base level, this sentence says "the family wants people to consider a donation."

Now slowly add those phrases back in:

> Which people?  Those "wishing to honor the mayor's memory."

> Donation to what?  The "Gotham Renewal Fund."

> Why the Gotham Renewal Fund?  It was "the cause most dear to his heart."

Comment: The padding comes from the high but common level of euphemism: As a reminder ...  the family asked ... those wishing to honor the memory ... consider ... dear to his heart. So much more polite than "You got cash? Pay here."